# Which hindu scriptures support the (modern) concept of manifesation

Tags: vedas, vedanta, smriti, sruti

There is a lot of propagation of the concept of LAW OF ATTRACTION in today's world. I also find [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_attraction_(New_Thought)#Philosophical_and_religious_basis) mentioning that Hinduism has significantly contributed to the creation of this (new age) concept.

Does Hindu Scriptures support this concept? What scriptures support the notion that thoughts manifest themselves?

When i say scriptures, i specifically mean texts like Sruti, Smriti (incl. Puranas) or Darshanas (Brahma Sutra etc.). If you come across any that supports it, please mention.

Comment: Brihadaranyaka Upanishad, 4.4.5 -says -"You are what your deep, driving desire is
As your desire is, so is your will
As your will is, so is your deed
As your deed is, so is your destiny"- काममया एवायं पुरुष इति ।
सा यथाकामो भवति तत्क्रतुर भवति ।।
यात्क्रतुर भवति तत कर्म कुरुते ।
यत कर्म कुरुते तद अभिसम पद्यते ।।

Comment: I also remember watching a documentary called "The secret" few years back.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar: Thanks. Yes, i too have watched "The Secret" but my goal is to reconcile the concept of Law of attraction / manifestation with what is said in Hindu Scriptures. I expect an answer in the lines of "Iccha Shakti" and its ability to make thoughts (drenched with belief) a reality. But i want a scriptural source that would define or defend this assumption.

Comment: Ok ,there is concept of Iccha Shakti called sankalpa here with us. Also above verse is indirectly saying about our own wish. Anyway will try to find more abt. wht. u want and will try to construct answer.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar: Thanks. Well, Varaha Upanishad deals with Sankalpa and it does say that Sankapla is the basis through which this world operates. I am yet to understand how it exactly happens- how thoughts manifest into experiences. The above verse you shared is also mentioned in the first 2 chapters of Souptika Parva (MBh) while referring to the way destiny operates. But, my scope is much more narrow, i am specifically interested to know if there is anything that directly translates to Law of Attraction or Manifestation as defined in Wiki.

Comment: Yes the Brahman created this universe with sankalpa itself. So it's applies to all if us also. But his intervention / will is also utmost necessary according to Upanishads.As he is the eye of the eye ,ear of the ear etc.